# Как добавить автоинкремент в уже собранную таблицу?

Tags: база-данных

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8b3V.png)
таблица была создана без авто-инкремента, в неё были добавлены данные и теперь надо включить авто-инкремент. Необходимо прописать автоинкремент в первичном ключе для юзера. user-id колонка должна быть настроена н как identity с автоинкременом 1. Объясните, пожалуйста, как я могу это сделать? СУБД SQL MS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Nowhere Man, да

Comment: @NowhereMan MSSQL

Comment: См. статью на англ. [Working With Identity Column After Table Creation In SQL Server](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-identity-column-after-table-creation-in-sql-server/) -- там описаны разные способы добавления авто-инкремента для MS SQL.

Comment: @NowhereMan все  заработало!Спасибо!!!

Comment: Если хотите, можете написать свой ответ с конкретным решением вашей проблемы

Comment: @NowhereMan проблему я решил ссылаясь на вашу статью, я зашел в SQL MS, База данных=>Таблица=>Проект=>Свойства столбца и раскрыл свойство "Спецификация Идентификации" и изменил на "да"